# Casting a Generic collection as a function parameter

Tags: java, generics, casting

I'm a little baffled at Java's(7) behaviour at this:

Say I have a ctor for `Foo` that takes a `Map<String,String>` as a parameter. The following code:

```
new Foo(ImmutableMap.of());
```

Produces the error Error:

> java: no suitable constructor found for
>   Foo(com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap)
>       constructor Foo(java.util.Map)
>   is not applicable

Trying to cast to `Map<String, String>` explicitly doesn't work as well as the compiler complains that the types are not convertible. However, this works just fine:

```
Map<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.of();
new Foo(map);
```

What the heck is going on here? Why does the compiler treat the local variable any differently than the function parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Java compiler doesn't seem to be able to infer the generic types from the constructor signature and falls back to the erased type (equivalent to `Map<Object, Object>`.)

Use:

```
new Foo(ImmutableMap.<String, String> of());
```

Comment: Great answer. It dawned on me that which constructor to call might be ambiguous (what if there is a second ctor that takes Map<Int,int>, then indeed it can't deduce which ctor to call)

Answer (score 4):

`ImmutableMap.of()` in method signature returns empty `Map<Object,Object>` which is get passed and for this type the constructor is not defined.

But when you use `Map<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.of();` than it returns specifically `Map<String ,String>`  in a pure *type-safe way*.

You should use it like this [`new Foo(ImmutableMap<String ,String>.of());`](https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#of%28%29)

Answer (score 4):

Java 7 needs the local variable to correctly infer the return type of the Immutable.of(). In Java 8, they improved this. See "improved type inference" here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/enhancements.html